# Mongoose : Trying to create a document in a callback, with values in an outer loop

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I stumbled upon a problem in mongoose recently, here's my code:

```
var v, query;
for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    v = values[i];
    query = model.findOne({type:v});
    query.exec(function(err, doc) {
      if(doc == undefined) {
        var m = new model({type:v, count:0});
        // but the 'v' above is not the values[i] in the for loop
        // code to save comes here
      } else {
        doc.count++;
        // update code comes here
      }
    });
}
```

I wanted to check if doc was null, and if so, enter a default value into the database. And if there was a doc returned, then update it's properties. The problem is that the object I'm trying to save has values[i] as one of it's properties. But since it's a callback, I do not get that particular value as it is in the for loop carries onward.

I got around this by inserting a default object for all the different values during model creation itself, but is there a way to do this at this point in the code flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
values.forEach(function(v) {
  var query = model.findOne({type:v});
  query.exec(function(err, doc) {
    if(doc == undefined) {
      var m = new model({type:v, count:0});
      // but the 'v' above is not the values[i] in the for loop
      // code to save comes here
    } else {
      doc.count++;
      // update code comes here
    }
  });
});
```

The reason it doesn't work with a `for` loop is because Javascript doesn't have a block scope, meaning that the `v` variable referenced in the block is reused instead of recreated.

When you use the variable immediately (like with `model.findOne({ type: v})` that's not a problem, but since the callback function for `query.exec` will (probably) execute after the loop has finished, the `v` variable in the callback will contain only the last value of `v` in the loop.

By using `forEach`, you *do* create a new `v` variable every time.